# $(this) children always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, undefined

I have problem with `undefined` being returned by `innerHTML`. Maybe it is because of a difference between `html()` and `innerHTML`?

My JavaScript code:

```
var content2 = document.getElementById("content2");
var opis;

$(function() {
  $('.blok').click(function(e) {
    opis = $(this).next('.opis');
    if (!$('.popup:visible').length) {
        content2.innerHTML= opis.html();
        $('.popup').fadeIn();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  $('.popup .close, .popup .bg').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.popup').fadeOut();
  });
})
```

My HTML:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" onselect="return false" oncopy="return false">
    <div class="popup"> 
        <div class="bg"></div> 
        <div class="container"> 
            <div id="content2"> </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    And example of "blok": 
    <div class="blok"> $$|DO| = |OC| = 5$$ <div class="opis">2</div>
</div>
```

Why does content2 always return `undefined`?

Comment: Where is your HTML ?

Comment: Stack overflow blocked to much code. Here it is:
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" onselect="return false" oncopy="return false">
<div class="popup">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

And example of "blok":
<div class="blok">
$$|DO| = |OC| = 5$$
<div class="opis">2</div>
</div>

Comment: Make sure as well that `var content2 = document.getElementById("content2");` is called when the element is already added to the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element with class `blok` and `opis` are not on the same level in the DOM structure. So `$(this).next('.opis')` is invalid. `jquery` `next()` is used when the elements are on the same DOM level. You need the following expression to get to the right element. `opis` is actually a child of `block`

```
 $('.blok').click(function(e) {
    opis = $(this).find('.opis');
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/pmnsvzrr/5/

OR

```
$('.blok').click(function(e) {
$(this).children('.opis');
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/pmnsvzrr/4/

Comment: But I need this() "opis" because I have lot of that constructions in my html:
<div class="blok">
<div class="opis"></div>
</div>

Comment: It is better but it always returns value of first noodle "opis" of first "blok" in html. I don't know why.

Comment: In your question, there is only one occurrence of div with class='opis'. If you have multiple, then you would need to use $.each function to get all the elements

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)